# Angular Router.navigate IntersectionObserver

Tags: angular, angular-router, intersection-observer

I'm relatively new to Angular (~2 months).

I have a sidebar menu and long content. Each of those sidebar menu items corresponds to different sections in the main content. When clicking on a menu item, I need to scroll to that section, and also scrolling the main content should also reflect the sidebar menu (currently 'visible' section) as well as url.

I'm using # fragment to uniquely identify sections. sidebar uses <a [routerLink] [fragment]> Main content has IntersectionObserver setup as follows:

```
new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
   ... some logic to determine which section is "visible"
  this.router.navigate([<url>], {fragment:<currentlyVisibleSectionId>})
})
```

this works, but it is extremely slow and jittery. i.e. when i scroll and the intersection changes, this.router.navigate is triggered and perhaps components are re-rendered but it interrupts scrolling for half a second or so and jumps. so without much luck, I switched it to good old javascript:

```
window.history.replaceState({},null,<new url>)
```

and manually passing the new fragment to sidebar

now the problem is the router/activatedroute isn't in sync with the current url. for instance, I am in #about, and i scroll to #contact section, I manually replace the hash to #contact, and update the sidebar to contact, but router/activatedroute still think i'm on #about. i.e. when i click "About" in the menu, activatedRoute.fragment doesn't trigger changes.

so yet again, a workaround is to instead of using [routerLink], i used (click) and manually trigger fragment update to parent components.

Well this works, but it's as dirty as it can get. is there a better way to do this? Thanks!